# because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs and webpack4, i am trying to link main.js file to index.html.I tried all the possible solutions on the web none of them seems to work for me..I am a newbie suggestions are welcome please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Here is the Error log what i am seeing:

---

```
GET http://localhost:3000/dist/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED
localhost/:1
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/dist/main.js' 
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

---

#### `public/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title> 
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### `/app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app  = express();
const http = require('http');

//Middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public' ));

app.post('/', function( req ,res){
    res.send("Success");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```

#### File structure

```
news_letter //Root directory
|_ dist
|   |_ main.js
|_ public
|   |_ index.html
|_ src
|   |_ index.js
|_ app.js
```

Answer (score 12):

you need the `main.js` file to be in the public folder.

It looks like you put the `main.js` file in `dist/` folder and `index.html` file in the `public/` folder.

but you only set one directory in your `app.js` file as a "static files directory"

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public' ));
```

every path in the html **is relative to the path in the public folder**. So, move your `dist/` folder into the `public/` folder and everything should work

#### File structure

```
news_letter //Root directory
|_ public
|   |_ dist
|   |   |_ main.js
|   |_ index.html
|_ src
|   |_ index.js
|_ app.js
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I also had to change the middleware line to:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public' ));
```

instead of:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public' ));
```

The reason based on the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) is:

> However, the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Comment: this solution helped me. I was using bootstrap sutdio as my front end designer, imported my html files using html2pug npm package and ended up with the same problem as OP. leaving the path `assets/js`, etc in my UI, I change the path `/public` to `/assets` and added `/assets` infront of the static path function as shown above.  `app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/assets')));`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

Adding below headers as middleware fixed in my case

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
  next();
});
```

Comment: What does this do, just ignores the issue?